# How to preserve HttpServletRequest autowiring when testing with SpringMVC Mockito and PowerMockito

Tags: spring-mvc, mockito, powermockito

Hi I'm trying to write some tests with Mockito and PowerMockito (I need to mock private methods) for a rest service written with SpringMVC and I'm facing the following issue

This is the semplified version of the controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
public class SimpleController {

    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/simpleservice", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public SimpleServiceResponse simpleService(@RequestBody SimpleServiceRequest simpleServiceRequest, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        SimpleServiceResponse simpleServiceResponse=new SimpleServiceResponse(simpleServiceRequest.getValue());
        httpRequest.getHeader("Header");
        return simpleServiceResponse;
    }

}
```

and this is the correspoding test class

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:WebApplicationContext.xml","classpath:SimpleApplicationContext.xml"})
@PrepareForTest(WebController.class)
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
public class TestSimpleControllerMockito {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestSimpleControllerMockito.class.getName());

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();

    @InjectMocks
    private SimpleController controller;

    @Test
    public void testSimpleService() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        SimpleService mockedSimple = mock(SimpleService.class);
        when(mockedSimple.doSimpleService(any(SimpleServiceRequest.class))).thenReturn(new SimpleServiceResponse("MockMock"));
        SimpleController mockedController=PowerMockito.spy(controller);

        SimpleServiceRequest simpleServiceRequest= new SimpleServiceRequest("ciao");
        String requestAsStr=objectMapper.writeValueAsString(simpleServiceRequest);
        MockMvc mMockMvc=MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(mockedController).build();
        MvcResult result= mMockMvc.perform(post("/test/simpleservice").content(requestAsStr).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andReturn();

        String content = result.getResponse().getContentAsString();
        SimpleServiceResponse simpleServiceResponse=objectMapper.readValue(content,SimpleServiceResponse.class);
        Assert.assertEquals("MockMockMockedSessionManager",simpleServiceResponse.getValue());


    }

}
```

When running the test case I got a NullPointerEception on `httpRequest.getHeader("Header");` 
My guess is that using the `@InjectMocks` annotation and then using

```
SimpleController mockedController=PowerMockito.spy(controller);
```

is the cause of the NullPointerException. I don't know how to preserve the @Autowire annotation processing on the controller Object. I already found a workaround, but it requires to write some redundant code.
Is there a way to make the @autowired annotation work?

Thanks a lot.

P.S.
the SimpleServiceXXX classes are like this one:

```
public class SimpleServiceResponse {

    private String value;

    public SimpleServiceResponse() {
    }

    public SimpleServiceResponse(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: You added a `@InjectMocks` annotation but currently you do not mock or inject anything at this point. Why not simply create a mock for `httpRequest`? I don't think you need a `spy` for the controller.

Comment: it's because this is a sample. In the real code there is a mocked object and this object is correctly injected into the controller. I'd like to have autowired working, otherwise I must duplicate header manager in post("/test/simpleservice").content(requestAsStr)... and the mocked httpRequest declared with Mock annotation